# Make function from image processing faster

Tags: c#, image-processing, bit-manipulation

This function is taken from some example of image processing and it returns value between 0 and 255:

```
private static byte CalculateColorComponentBlendValue(float source, float overlay)
{
    float resultValue = 0;
    byte resultByte = 0;

    resultValue = source + overlay;

    if (resultValue > 255)
    {
        resultByte = 255;
    }
    else if (resultValue < 0)
    {
        resultByte = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        resultByte = (byte)resultValue;
    }

    return resultByte;
}
```

And it is called in a big loop. Can this somehow be optimized? May be with some bits manipulations? Now the whole loop takes 400ms and if I remove calls to this function it reduces to 200ms.

Comment: One simple thing I can think of is check the distribution of `source + overlay` values so that the predicate with the highest probability is examined first.

Comment: how big is the loop?

Comment: How do you measure it? Do you run in release without compiler attached?

Comment: @Euphoric, with stopwatch in debug mode.

Comment: @Mark, loop is 2,560,000(image is 1600x1600) and the function is called 3 times per iteration

Comment: Then make sure you run it in release without debugger attached. Simple methods like this can be heavily optimized by compiler, drastically improving performance. Maybe you will find this method has minimal impact on speed after compiler optimizes it.

Comment: @Euphoric, ok I will test in release mode now

Comment: @Euphoric, it dropped to 100ms in release mode. That is more than satisfactory... Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You could try Numerics.Vector and do a bunch of them at once

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve here is called clamping. It has been discussed several times before. I'd suggest you to look at those discussions. So rather than repeating those, I'll pose some questions instead. Does your implementation need to be purely C? Does the value need to be float? Are other optimisation options available to you: SIMD, thread, GPU?